# How to get "275,47" value (BeautifulSoup,Python3)

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new in web scraping, so I need your help.
I have this html code (look at the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiaxl.png)) and I want to get this specific value --> "275,47".
 I wrote down this code, but something is going wrong... Please help me! :)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url="https://www.skroutz.gr/s/11504255/Apple-iPhone-SE-32GB.html"
page=requests.get(url)
soup=bs(page.text,"html.parser")

D={"href":"/products/show/30871132","rel":"nofollow","class":"js-product- 
   link","data-func":"trigger_shop_uservoice","data-uservoice- 
   pid":"30871132","data-append-element":".shop-details","data-uservoice- 
   shopid":"1913","data-type":"final_price"}

value=soup.find_all("a",attrs=D)
print(value.string)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are close! Your error is being thrown because the variable "value" does not have an attribute called string. Value is currently a list of items. You want to iterate over all of the anchors and find the one you are looking for.

My suggestion:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url="https://www.skroutz.gr/s/11504255/Apple-iPhone-SE-32GB.html"
page=requests.get(url)
soup=bs(page.text,"html.parser")

value=soup.find_all("a")

for item in value:
    if '30871132' in item.get('href'):
        print item.text
```

item will be the current anchor tag we are iterating over in the loop.

We can get it's href attribute (or any attribute) by using the .get method.

We then check if '308711332' is in the href, and if so, print out it's text.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply to my question!  Your information was valuable to me :)